# How to callback function result initial route determined in react native.?

Tags: navigation, react-native, facebook-login, login-page

Login is the first route each time.

I want to show the tabpage  if user login. Otherwise, I want to navigate  to the login page.

```
class blabla extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        user: null
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     var _this = this;
      FBLoginManager.getCredentials(function(error, data){
        if (!error) {
          _this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
        } else {
          _this.setState({ user : null });
        }
      });
  }
  render() {
  console.log(this.state.user)
  // 1. render -> null 
  // 2. render -> data 
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS ref="navigator"
        style={styles.nav}
        initialRoute={{
          title: "blabla",
          component: this.state.user != null  ? TabPage : Login,
        }} />
    );
  }
}
```

**Solved** this problem , I use twice statement and replace the code es6 syntax to es5 because I don't know  use `if( !_this.isMounted() ) return;` in es6 syntax .

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      credentials: undefined,
      load:true
    };
  },


  componentDidMount: function(){
    var _this = this;
    FBLoginManager.getCredentials(function(error, data){
      if( !_this.isMounted() ) return;
      if (!error) {
        _this.setState({ credentials : data.credentials,load:false });
      } else {
        _this.setState({ credentials : false,load:false });
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.load) {
      return <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center"}}><Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>loading...</Text></View>
    }
    return <NavigatorIOS ref="nav"
        style={{flex:1}}
        navigationBarHidden={false}
        rightButtonTitle="Profile"
        onRightButtonPress= {() => this.left()}
        initialRoute={{
          title: "AnsApp",
          component: this.state.credentials != undefined && this.state.credentials != false ? TabPage : Profile ,
        }} />
  },
```

Comment: You should put your solution in an ANSWER and not into the question. Then you can accept the answer and the problem will be marked as resolved.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you. It's saturday and I'm working hard on my portfolio, but I did some improvements and clarified some parts. Feel free to ask me if you have questions :smiley:

```
 class blabla extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        user: null ,
        loggedInn: !true
      }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     var _this = this;
      FBLoginManager.getCredentials(function(error, data){
        if (this.state.loggedInn = !true) {
          _this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
        }
           return this.state;
      });
  },
  Logon () {
   // your this.state validation 
  }
  render() {
  console.log(this.state.user)
  // 1. render -> null 
  // 2. render -> data 
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS ref="navigator"
        style={styles.nav}
        initialRoute={{
          title: "blabla",
          component: this.state == Logon ? TabPage : Login,
        }} />
    );
  }
}
```